# JSON schema : "allof" with "additionalProperties"

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema

Suppose we have schema following schema (from tutorial [here](http://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#structuring)):

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",

  "definitions": {
    "address": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "street_address": { "type": "string" },
        "city":           { "type": "string" },
        "state":          { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": ["street_address", "city", "state"]
    }
  },

  "type": "object",

  "properties": {
    "billing_address": { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" },
    "shipping_address": {
      "allOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" },
        { "properties":
          { "type": { "enum": [ "residential", "business" ] } },
          "required": ["type"]
        }
      ]
    } 

  }
}
```

And here is valid instance:

```
{
      "shipping_address": {
        "street_address": "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW",
        "city": "Washington",
        "state": "DC",
        "type": "business"
      }
}
```

I need to ensure that any additional fields for `shipping_address` will be invalid. I know for this purpose exists `additionalProperties` which should be set to "false". But when I'm setting `"additionalProprties":false` as in the following:

```
"shipping_address": {
          "allOf": [
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" },
            { "properties":
              { "type": { "enum": [ "residential", "business" ] } },
              "required": ["type"]
            }
          ],
          "additionalProperties":false
        }
```

I get a validation error (checked [here](http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/index.jsp)):

```
[ {
  "level" : "error",
  "schema" : {
    "loadingURI" : "#",
    "pointer" : "/properties/shipping_address"
  },
  "instance" : {
    "pointer" : "/shipping_address"
  },
  "domain" : "validation",
  "keyword" : "additionalProperties",
  "message" : "additional properties are not allowed",
  "unwanted" : [ "city", "state", "street_address", "type" ]
} ]
```

The question is: how should I to limit fields for the `shipping_address` part only?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 109):

You can now do this with spec [2019-09](https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-core.html#unevaluatedProperties) with `"unevaluatedProperties": false`

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/2019-09/schema#",

  "definitions": {
    "address": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "street_address": { "type": "string" },
        "city":           { "type": "string" },
        "state":          { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": ["street_address", "city", "state"]
      // additionalProperties: false    // <-- Remove completely if present 
    }
  },

  "type": "object",

  "properties": {
    "billing_address": { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" },
    "shipping_address": {
      "unevaluatedProperties": false,   // <-- Add to same level as allOf as false
      "allOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" },
        { "properties":
          { "type": { "enum": [ "residential", "business" ] } },
          "required": ["type"]
        }
      ]
    } 
  }
}
```

A pretty clear and succinct explanation can be found by the author [here](https://gist.github.com/handrews/6dfebd56ef97328f9e4dc7a47a1e8bc7?permalink_comment_id=2367396#gistcomment-2367396);

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. As I understand "strictProperties" and "merge" are part of v5 spec. Is there existing stable validators supporting v5? Thanks

Comment: Those two properties are not part of any spec - they are features that @fge is *proposing*, so there's no guarantee they'll be in any future version.

Comment: @fge - it's kinda not obvious in your answer that the keywords are not part of a spec, but are your proposed extension.  They way they are presented makes them seem like an official solution without any warning that v5 is in flux, which I think is misleading.

Comment: There is not need to improve draft V3 to solve this problem with an elegant solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24365393/1480391

Comment: @fge is still not clear to me how you can combine more than 2 schemas (i.e. 3 entire schemas) into one with $merge . For some reasons I thought allOf it's a kind of storage/embedding method for multiple schemas with  the only rule being to not have conflicting properties.

Comment: Sadly it seems v5 spec only turned out to be a maintenance spec.
https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/v5-Proposals
Is there any thing that would solve this issue in v6?

Comment: Currently at v7 and I don't see any `merge` or `strictProperties`. Is it now possible to do what the OP is talking about ?

Comment: @JulianHonma January, 2019 `strictProperties` and `merge` are not part of spec draft v7.

Comment: They're now at version [2019-09](https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/release-notes.html) and still no sign of improvements in this area.

Comment: From 2019-09 on there is "unevaluatedProperties" which can be set to false. This will finally solve the problem here.

Comment: @AndreasH. Unfortunately does not solve. with "additionalProperties" my validator clearly inform me that some property is absent. But with "unevaluatedProperties" it reports me all the properties which did not pass validation (length, dataType etc) , even if they are present in response.  And the validator does not inform WHY the validation  failed. So it is too hard to find the reson of failed validation: either invalid schema or invalid reponse

Comment: @OleksandrKulychok Hmm, maybe that is a validator problem? It is hard to tell without seeing the schema + data. Maybe you want to post a new question?

Answer (score 14):

`additionalProperties` applies to all properties that are not accounted-for by `properties` or `patternProperties` in the *immediate schema*.

This means that when you have:

```
    {
      "allOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" },
        { "properties":
          { "type": { "enum": [ "residential", "business" ] } },
          "required": ["type"]
        }
      ],
      "additionalProperties":false
    }
```

`additionalProperties` here applies to *all* properties, because there is no sibling-level `properties` entry - the one inside `allOf` does not count.

One thing you could do is to move the `properties` definition one level up, and provide stub entries for properties you are importing:

```
    {
      "allOf": [{"$ref": "#/definitions/address"}],
      "properties": {
        "type": {"enum": ["residential", "business"]},
        "addressProp1": {},
        "addressProp2": {},
        ...
      },
      "required": ["type"],
      "additionalProperties":false
    }
```

This means that `additionalProperties` will not apply to the properties you want.

Comment: Thanks for reply , but it was not help : here is error : [ {
  "level" : "error",
  "schema" : {
    "loadingURI" : "#",
    "pointer" : "/properties/shipping_address"
  },
  "instance" : {
    "pointer" : "/shipping_address"
  },
  "domain" : "validation",
  "keyword" : "additionalProperties",
  "message" : "additional properties are not allowed",
  "unwanted" : [ "city", "state", "street_address" ]
} ] - same as before.

Comment: Did you import "city" "state" and "street_address", like "addressProp1" in my example?

Comment: Can you clarify ? I changed schema according to your changes. "city" "state" and "street_address" remain part of referenced schema, did you mean it ? I checked with validator  http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/

Comment: That's currently the only working solution, albeit rather cumbersome (when you have to add a dozen properties just to keep the `"additionalProperties": false` happy)

Comment: Not working :/ .

Answer (score 8):

Here's a slightly simplified version of [Yves-M's Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24365393/776186):

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "address": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "street_address": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "city": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "state": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "street_address",
        "city",
        "state"
      ]
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "billing_address": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/address"
    },
    "shipping_address": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/address"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "enum": [
            "residential",
            "business"
          ]
        },
        "street_address": {},
        "city": {},
        "state": {}
      },
      "required": [
        "type"
      ],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  }
}
```

This preserves the validation of required properties in the base `address` schema, and just adds the required `type` property in the `shipping_address`.

It's unfortunate that `additionalProperties` only takes the immediate, sibling-level properties into account. Maybe there is a reason for this. But this is why we need to repeat the inherited properties.

Here, we're repeating the inherited properties in simplified form, using empty object syntax. This means that properties with these names would be valid no matter what kind of value they contained. But we can rely on the `allOf` keyword to enforce the type constraints (and any other constraints) declared in the base `address` schema.

Comment: this is one of the best examples I've read that explains the full picture. Thanks @ted epstein

Comment: Thanks, @Brett! Glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Since no one has posted a valid answer for spec [2019-09](https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-core.html#unevaluatedProperties) and upwards and I almost missed Andreas H.'s comment;

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/2019-09/schema#",

  "definitions": {
    "address": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "street_address": { "type": "string" },
        "city":           { "type": "string" },
        "state":          { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": ["street_address", "city", "state"]
      // additionalProperties: false    // <-- Remove completely if present 
    }
  },

  "type": "object",

  "properties": {
    "billing_address": { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" },
    "shipping_address": {
      "unevaluatedProperties": false,   // <-- Add to same level as allOf as false
      "allOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" },
        { "properties":
          { "type": { "enum": [ "residential", "business" ] } },
          "required": ["type"]
        }
      ]
    } 
  }
}
```

A pretty clear and succinct explanation can be found by the author [here](https://gist.github.com/handrews/6dfebd56ef97328f9e4dc7a47a1e8bc7?permalink_comment_id=2367396#gistcomment-2367396);

Comment: This is the right idea but the code is invalid because `unevaluatedProperties` is only valid in draft 2019-09 or newer.   this answer should be updated to indicate the proper `$schema` version

Answer (score 2):

### Don't set additionalProperties=false at definition level

And everything will be fine:

```
{    
    "definitions": {
        "address": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "street_address": { "type": "string" },
                "city":           { "type": "string" },
                "state":          { "type": "string" }
            }
        }
    },

    "type": "object",
    "properties": {

        "billing_address": {
            "allOf": [
                { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" }
            ],
            "properties": {
                "street_address": {},
                "city": {},
                "state": {}                 
            },          
            "additionalProperties": false
            "required": ["street_address", "city", "state"] 
        },

        "shipping_address": {
            "allOf": [
                { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" },
                {
                    "properties": {
                        "type": {
                            "enum": ["residential","business"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "properties": {
                "street_address": {},
                "city": {},
                "state": {},
                "type": {}                          
            },              
            "additionalProperties": false
            "required": ["street_address","city","state","type"] 
        }

    }
}
```

Each of your `billing_address` and `shipping_address` should specify their own required properties.

Your definition should not have `"additionalProperties": false` if you want to combine his properties with other ones.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, the definition of billing_address pulls in by reference the properties street_address, city and state; then it defines them again locally.  Is that right?  The shipping_address seems to do something similar.  It appears redundant, and my goal of using $ref is to avoid repeating definitions. Pls tell me, what does this achieve?

Comment: You have to specify `street_address`, `city` and `state` again in `properties` in order to use them in `required`, that's why they are in `properties` with `{}`

Comment: "You have to specify street_address, city and state again in properties in order to use them in required, that's why they are in properties with {}". What no you don't. not according to the spec anyway. required, and properties are independent.

Comment: This clearly violates [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), which is the reason why OP asked this question in the first place

Comment: I'd agree that this voilates DRY. Besides that it produces less-readable code and is in no way intuitive. I'm not sure if there's a reason why additionalProperties only looks at the sibling-level when checking allowed properties but IMHO this should be changed.