# How to use additionalProperties with allOf in JSON schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Consider this example:

```
"allOf": [
    {"$ref": "test-address-prefix-types-base.json#"},
    {
        "properties": {}, "additionalProperties" : false
    }
]}
```

When I validate this with Java schema validator, I get error saying:

```
"keyword":"additionalProperties","message":"object instance has properties which are not allowed by the schema: [\"attributes\",\"type\"]"}]
```

but the same JSON object validated against the base schema (test-address-prefix-types-base) passes without error.

The referenced schema (base one) doesn't have additionalProperties set.

This is the json message I am using:

```
        String message = "{\"data\":{\"attributes\":{" +
            "\"notation\": \"A\"," +
            "\"prefixType\": \"A\"}" +
            ",\"type\":\"test-address-prefix-types\"}}";
```

Have I missed anything in schema?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your schema could be expanded this way:

`allof`: It must validate `independently` against two schemas:

- First one with arbitrary properties linked through `ref`.
- The second one which does not allow any property `"additionalProperties" : false` except those defined in the empty set `"properties" : {}`. In other words, it can not have any property.

This problem may be solved in draft-5 of the standard. More on this in [the following SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22689900/json-schema-allof-with-additionalproperties).

Comment: So the question is, this "merge" is only a proposal and not released yet, right? I've checked the json schema spec in http://json-schema.org/ and there is no mention of it. We are using AJV to validate and that's not supporting the merge yet.

Comment: Yes, you can not apply it safely yet. If possible, you may add "additionalProperties" : false to the referenced schema.

Comment: Do you know if Json Schema Validator (https://github.com/daveclayton/json-schema-validator) supports $merge? I just realized that AJV added the support of $merge but we are using Json schema validator which is for Java and from what I can see here https://github.com/daveclayton/json-schema-validator/wiki/v5:-merge it supports $merge but I just can't get it working? It returns errors as $merge is not recognized