# Swagger Codegen OneOf generating incorrectly

Tags: openapi, swagger-codegen

I am generating a JavaClient using an OpenAPISpec document. I have used `swagger-codegen 3.0` to generate the code. The OpenAPISpec version is `3.0.1`.

Below is the OpenAPI snippet I am facing problems with:

```
"RequestWithInsuranceInfo": {
        "type": "object",
        "description": "This request schema will produce a response containing an out of pocket estimate for the given service using the patient's insurance information.",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
          "insuranceInfo": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/InsuranceInfo"
          },
          "service": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "description": "Schema to use when the patient's benefit info is not given in the request.",
            "properties": {
              "codes": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ServiceCode"
                }
              },
              "provider": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Provider"
              },
              "costs": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ServiceCosts"
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "codes",
              "provider",
              "costs"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
"InsuranceInfo": {
        "description": "Information about the payer, plan, and members.",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "oneOf": [
          {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "title": "Option 1: Patient Is Policy Holder",
            "description": "Schema to use when the patient the primary on the insurance plan.",
            "properties": {
              "payer": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Payer"
              },
              "policyHolderInfo": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/PolicyHolderInfo"
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "payer",
              "policyHolderInfo"
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "title": "Option 2: Patient Is Dependent",
            "description": "Schema to use when the patient is a dependent on the insurance plan.",
            "properties": {
              "payer": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Payer"
              },
              "dependentMemberInfo": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/DependentMemberInfo"
              },
              "policyHolderInfo": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/PolicyHolderInfo"
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "payer",
              "dependentMemberInfo",
              "policyHolderInfo"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
```

Below is the code which gets generated:

```
public class InsuranceInfo implements OneOfInsuranceInfo {

  @Override
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object o) {..}

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {..}

  @Override
  public String toString() {..}

  private String toIndentedString(java.lang.Object o) {..}
}


public interface OneOfInsuranceInfo {

}


public class RequestWithInsuranceInfo implements OneOfRequest {
  @SerializedName("insuranceInfo")
  private InsuranceInfo insuranceInfo = null;

  @SerializedName("service")
  private RequestWithInsuranceInfoService service = null;
 ..

}

public class Payer {
  @SerializedName("id")
  private String id = null;
  
  ..
}

public class PolicyHolderInfo {
  @SerializedName("memberId")
  private String memberId = null;

  @SerializedName("firstName")
  private String firstName = null;

  @SerializedName("lastName")
  private String lastName = null;

  @SerializedName("dateOfBirth")
  private LocalDate dateOfBirth = null;

  ..
}

public class DependentMemberInfo {
  @SerializedName("memberId")
  private String memberId = null;

  @SerializedName("firstName")
  private String firstName = null;

  @SerializedName("lastName")
  private String lastName = null;

  @SerializedName("dateOfBirth")
  private LocalDate dateOfBirth = null;

  ..

}
```

As shown, the `InsuranceInfo` object implements the `OneOfInsuranceInfo` interface but has no variables. Payer, PolicyHolderInfo and dependentMemberInfo class are generated but they are not linked to the InsuranceInfo class anyhow. How do I populate the InsuranceInfo class?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably that the `InsuranceInfo` schema

```json
"InsuranceInfo": {
  "description": "Information about the payer, plan, and members.",

  "additionalProperties": false,
  "oneOf": [
    { ... },
    { ... }
  ]
}
```

effectively **disallows ALL properties**. This is because `additionalProperties: false` only knows about the `properties` defined directly alongside it and [has no visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22693428/113116) into `oneOf` subschemas.

To resolve the issue, you can rewrite the `InsuranceInfo` schema without `oneOf`, as follows. This schema is basically "Option 2" from the original schema, except the `dependentMemberInfo` property is defined as optional.

```json
"InsuranceInfo": {
  "description": "Information about the payer, plan, and members.",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "payer",
    "policyHolderInfo"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "payer": {
      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Payer"
    },
    "dependentMemberInfo": {
      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/DependentMemberInfo"
    },
    "policyHolderInfo": {
      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/PolicyHolderInfo"
    }
  }
}
```