# Which is the correct allOf syntax for OpenAPI 3 schema inheritance?

Tags: swagger, openapi

Which syntax is correct - the first one, the second one, or both?

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    FileContent:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/FileInfo'
        - type: object
          properties:
            storageMethod:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/StorageMethod'
            contentRange:
              type: string
              nullable: true
            # ... other properties ...
          additionalProperties: false
```

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    FileContent:
      type: object
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/FileInfo'
      properties:
        storageMethod:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/StorageMethod'
        contentRange:
          type: string
          nullable: true
        # ... other properties ...
      additionalProperties: false
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of `allOf` syntax, both versions are correct and technically equivalent:

```yaml
allOf:
  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'
  - properties:
      # other properties
      # ...
```

```yaml
allOf:
  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'
properties:
  # other properties
  # ...
```

In OpenAPI 3.1 (which uses JSON Schema 2020-12 by default), there's even no need for `allOf` if you only have one `$ref` because `$ref` now [allows sibling keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41752575/113116). (But you still need `allOf` to "combine" multiple $refs.)

```yaml
# openapi: 3.1.0

$ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'
properties:
  # other properties
  # ...
```

**The error in your examples is elsewhere** - it's the presence of `additionalProperties: false`. This keyword is problematic because it only knows about its immediate sibling `properties` and has [no visibility into allOf/oneOf/anyOf subschemas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22693428/113116) or "inherited" schemas. For your examples, this means that properties defined in the `FileInfo` schema won't actually be allowed in the composed schema.

Here are some more examples to illustrate that `additionalProperties: false` doesn't work the way one would expect:

```yaml
allOf:
  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'
  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Bar'
additionalProperties: false

# Expected: Only the properties defined in Foo and Bar are allowed
# Actual: No properties are allowed
```

```yaml
allOf:
  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'
  - properties:
      prop:
        type: string
    additionalProperties: false

# Expected: The allowed properties are `prop` and those defined in the Foo schema
# Actual: Only the `prop` property is allowed
```

```yaml
allOf:
  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'
properties:
  prop:
    type: string
additionalProperties: false

# Expected: The allowed properties are `prop` and those defined in the Foo schema
# Actual: Only the `prop` property is allowed
```

```yaml
Foo:
  type: object
  properties:
    foo:
      type: string
  additionalProperties: false

Bar:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'
    - properties:
        prop:
          type: string

# Expected: The Bar schema allows properties from Foo + the `prop` property
# Actual: The Bar schema allows only properties from Foo
```

This is solved in OpenAPI 3.1 / JSON Schema 2019-09+ by the new [`unevaluatedProperties: false`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#unevaluated-properties) keyword. So the following will work the way you expect:

```yaml
# openapi: 3.1.0

$ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'
properties:
  prop:
    type: string
unevaluatedProperties: false
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the second one: for a long time, schema keywords adjacent to $ref were ignored in json schemas. Later they changed it in the spec (AFAIK), but I'm not sure if all the tooling & implementations caught up with that.

Yet my personal preference is putting both the parent schema and child schema props under an `allOf`, like

```
  schemas:
    FileContent:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/FileInfo'
        - type: object
          properties:
            storageMethod:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/StorageMethod'
            contentRange:
              type: string
              nullable: true
            totalLength:
              type: integer
              format: int64
```